# In Shadow Hunters, can only Hunters benefit from the Spear of Longinus?

Tags: shadow-hunters

Spear of Longinus text:

> If you're a Hunter and your attack is successful, you may reveal your identity. If you do, or if you are already revealed, you give 2 points of extra damage.

If a revealed, non-Hunter has the spear do they inflict the extra damage?

I think the intent of the card was probably to only benefit Hunters, but it could be read as any revealed character using the spear gives the extra damage. But, only Hunters would get the ability to reveal their identity on a successful attack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I read it, "If you're a Hunter" applies to the entire rules paragraph.  Therefore, you could re-read it as:

> If you're a Hunter and your attack is successful, you may reveal your identity.  If you're a Hunter and you do, or if you are already revealed, you give 2 points of extra damage."

I could certainly see the argument, though, that two sentences are two completely separate, and so that any revealed non-Hunter could do 2 points of extra damage as well.  I believe the intent is for Hunters only, but it isn't very clear.